# Avoiding rerenders when using React Context

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-rerender-2epyq?file=/src/index.tsx)

I am using context to the state of various components, in this case, which checkbox is checked, and am using that component to mutate that component state. However, by clicking only one checkbox, all four components (checkboxes) rerender. How can I prevent this rerendering when hooking into and mutating context? Thanks.

**index.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { ContextProvider, useMyContext } from "./context";
import "./styles.css";

const Checkbox: React.FC<{ id: number }> = ({ id }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => console.log(`Checkbox ${id} Render`));

  const { setValue, value } = useMyContext();

  return (
    <input
      onClick={() => setValue(id)}
      checked={id === value}
      type="checkbox"
    />
  );
};

const Container: React.FC = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => console.log("Container Render"));

  return (
    <div>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3].map(id => (
        <Checkbox id={id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <Container />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**context.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";

interface ContextState {
  setValue: (id: number) => void;
  value: number;
}

const initialContextState: ContextState = {
  setValue: () => {},
  value: 0
};

const Context = React.createContext<ContextState>(initialContextState);

export const ContextProvider: React.FC = (props: object) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number>(0);

  return (
    <Context.Provider
      value={{
        setValue,
        value
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export const useMyContext = (): ContextState => React.useContext(Context);
```

Comment: Please put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: Please take a minute to actually read what I posted. That's a *link*, not a MRE.

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent the rerender of the context-consuming component (`Checkbox` in your example) - the forced rerender when the context value is updated is just how the Context API works, you can't apply any 'selectivity' to it.

What you *can* do is take the expensive part of the actual content of that consuming component, extract it into a child component wrapped with `React.memo` (or inline it as a chunk of JSX wrapped in a `useMemo` hook - [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)), get the values you need from the context and pass those as props to that child component / dependencies to the `useMemo` section.

The built in memoisation will then 'just work' and will not rerender the child component (the expensive part) for the checkboxes whose actual value doesn't update, as the relevant props will not change.

Using memoisation like this can solve any actual performance issues you need to address, but just a reminder that 90% of the time, this stuff just doesn't matter. Test and determine performance is actually an issue before you refactor your components in this way. It's usually simply not worth the extra indirection to solve a non-problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-normal-5vchh?file=/src/Field.js) you can find a similar example,

using this library [react-hooks-in-callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-in-callback) you can filter out all unnecessary re-renders

check the result [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-with-hooks-in-callback-jeo4i?file=/src/Field.js)